# Keyboard layout not working, dead keys come alive at random times

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I am using the keyboard layout English (US international with dead keys). I type in English and in Portuguese, which makes use of characters such as "ç" and "é".

When I discovered this layout it worked beautifully: I type "'", nothing happens, then I type "e", and "é" is produced. Then all of a sudden the dead keys had risen from their graves: trying to do the same above would produce this: 'e.

I played around changing keyboard layouts back and forth and then all of a sudden it started working again.

Is this a bug? Couldn't find anything exactly like I am experiencing. Any workarounds?

Edit: forgot to mention, running 12.04 here.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have more than one keyboard layout in your "Text entry" configurations and check if you have some shortcut to switch between these layouts. It seems you are swithing between English (US international with dead keys) and English (US).

Remove the unused layout and remove the shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For many other little issues I was experiencing I switched to Linux Mint and everything seems to work fine now.